# preg match numbers from $variable

Tags: php, regex

lets say I have this:

```
$id = "bla bla 123 number/4567''' ";
```

Then, I want to add an preg_match that filter only the number 4567. the only stable thing from the $id is number/xxxx so when it find this structure number/xxxx or number/xxxxxxxx (it doesn't matter how many numbers are, put that numbers intro a var called $a.

Example:

```
input: $id = "bla bla 434323 123  number/456789abc "; 
In this case $a will take the value 456789
```

But, what about this situation:

```
input: $id = "bla bla number/123 bla bla number/456 bla bla number/789xx ";
in this situation I want to get all matches like this:

$a will be 123
$b will be 456
$c will be 789
```

This doesn't work:

```
<?php

$id = "bla bla number/123  number/456789abc "; 

function find_in_id_content($id)
{

if ( preg_match_all('#(?<=number/)\d+#', $str, $m ) ) {
    list($a, $b, $c, $d) = $m[0];
    printf("a=%s,b=%s,c=%s\n", $a, $b, $c);
}
}
echo $a;
?>
```

Comment: Use http://php.net/preg_match_all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
if ( preg_match_all('#(?<=number/)\d+#', $str, $m ) ) {
    list($a, $b, $c, $d) = $m[0];
    printf("a=%s,b=%s,c=%s\n", $a, $b, $c);
}
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
a=123,b=456,c=789
```

Comment: and how does it know this script to search only in $id content? and then I need variables like $a to take that number, I don't know what to do with that array and how to put it intro $a $b $c ...

Comment: This captures numbers that are followed by string `number/`. To put them in variables you can do: `$a=$m[0][0]; $b=$m[0][1]; $c=$m[0][2];`

Comment: or, if it's more simple, without that $a $b $c variables, I what to echo an list with that numbers, but add a link to each number to this adress www.example.com/file.php?x=(that number)

Comment: `foreach($m[0] as $number) echo '<a href="www.example.com/file.php?x=$number">Link</a>';`

Comment: @user3314333: check updated answer on how to populate `$a, $b, $c` from resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/number\/([0-9]+)/', $id, $matches);
```